# OmniPay manually "create" a response class?

Tags: omnipay, mollie

So I'm using https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-mollie and I've decided to use webhooks instead of the example they have on their readme. I've got all that working but when it comes time to process the webhook, I was hoping to have access to the helper functions such as `isPending`, `isRefunded`, etc...

However, because this hasn't been put into the AbstractResponse class, they aren't available. Usually, OmniPay lets you use a method called `acceptNotification()` that parses the request and puts it into an AbstractResponse class so that you can use these helper methods.

Problem is, for whatever reason, omnipay-mollie doesn't allow you to use this function. So I'm stuck trying to find a way to manually force my webhook request into this AbstractClass so that I can use these helper functions. I've dug around the entire OmniPay and OmniPay-Mollie source code and cannot find any sort of way to instantiate the class or anything like that.

Hopefully someone with more experience can lend a hand.

Comment: Can you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43775616/, this explains it pretty well, I think.